# No error found but the app hangs in the Looper

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I implements the CirclePagerIndicator of JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator and the AutoScrollViewPager https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager in my code. It build fine without any errors, but when it is open, nothing appear, just white board with the Actionbar on the top, afterwards, I debug it, I find the code hangs up at Loop function in the logcat just shows to me "application is running" it is frozen here ,specially at msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg) in the Looper function;

The tricky part is that if I remove the

```
circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

everything works fine like normally, but without it,I will not have indicator. I spend 3 days on it, can not find any answers. THANKS!

my code is listed below:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.R;
import com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.SlidingSwitcherView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.*;
import me.maxwin.view.*;
import com.viewpagerindicator.*;

public class Fragment_home extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private AutoScrollViewPager viewPager;
    private List<Integer>       imageIdList;
    private TextView            indexText;
    private int position_1;
    private float y1=0f,y2=0f;
    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator;


    public static Fragment_home newInstance(int position) {
        Fragment_home f = new Fragment_home();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        position_1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        //Context contextThemeWrapper =new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_PageIndicatorDefaults);

        final XListView list = (XListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_home);
        View header= inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_inlistview,list,false);
        //inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
        circlePageIndicator= (CirclePageIndicator)header.findViewById(R.id.titles);
        viewPager= (AutoScrollViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.aotu_viewpager);
        //indexText= (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_index);


        imageIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        imageIdList.add(R.drawable.a);
        imageIdList.add(R.drawable.b);
        imageIdList.add(R.drawable.c);
        imageIdList.add(R.drawable.d);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(getActivity(), imageIdList).setInfiniteLoop(true));
        //viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener());
        circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        //circlePageIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener());

        viewPager.setInterval(4000);
       // viewPager.setSlideBorderMode(1);
        viewPager.startAutoScroll();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 - Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 % ListUtils.getSize(imageIdList));



       //circlePageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), SlidingSwitcherView.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        });
        list.addHeaderView(header,null,true);
        list.setAdapter(new myBasicAdapter(getActivity()));
//        list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
//
//
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//                 if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//                     y1=event.getY();
//                 }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
//                     y2=event.getY();
//                 }
//                if(Math.abs(y1-y2)>3){
//                    return true;
//                }
//                else return false;
//            }
//        });
         viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//                     y1=event.getY();
//                 }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
//                     y2=event.getY();
//                 }
//                if(Math.abs(y1-y2)>3){
//               //    viewPager.setSlideBorderMode(2);
//                }
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }

        });
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Object obj = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);


                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), SlidingSwitcherView.class);
                switch (position){
                    case 0: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 1: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 2: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 3: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 4: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 5: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 6: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 7: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 8: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 9: startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 10: startActivity(intent);break;

                }


            }
        });

        return view;


    }



    public class MyOnPageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//            indexText.setText(new StringBuilder().append((position) % ListUtils.getSize(imageIdList) + 1).append("/")
//                    .append(ListUtils.getSize(imageIdList)));
          //  circlePageIndicator.onPageSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
           // circlePageIndicator.onPageScrolled(position,positionOffset,positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
          //  circlePageIndicator.onPageScrollStateChanged(arg0);
        }
    }

    class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


        public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.title1,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
      //  setListAdapter(adapter);
      // getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }

    class Single_row{

        String pic;
        String description;
        String text;
        Single_row(String pic,String description,String text){
            this.pic=pic;
            this.description=description;
        }
    }

    class myBasicAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ArrayList<Single_row> list;

        Context context;
        myBasicAdapter(Context c){

            list=new ArrayList<Single_row>();
            context=c;

            Resources res=getResources();
            String []pic= res.getStringArray(R.array.picture1);
            String []description=res.getStringArray(R.array.discription);
            String []text=res.getStringArray(R.array.discription);

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                list.add(new Single_row(pic[i],description[i],text[i]));
            }

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
            TextView textView= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            TextView  textView2= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description);
            Single_row temp=list.get(position);
            textView.setText(temp.pic);
            textView2.setText(temp.description);

            return row;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // stop auto scroll when onPause
        viewPager.stopAutoScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // start auto scroll when onResume
        viewPager.startAutoScroll();
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ARG_POSITION+" "+position_1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//    }



}
```

Comment: Where is `ImagePagerAdapter`? How you are setting infinite loop? Can you remove your infinite loop call and then check it?

Comment: cooooooool! I remove the infinite loop, and it's working!!!thank you!